# How to delete dynamic cfm file only AFTER the code runs?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfthread

I'm using the in-memory file system to execute dynamic CFM files. How can I  delete the temporary file only AFTER it is finished running? If I do it right after the cfinclude, it won't get deleted if the dynamic code has an abort or location tag etc.
Can I create a thread that will sleep till the main page thread completes and then delete it?

Comment: Put them all in a certain directory and set up a scheduled job to delete them.

Comment: A thread should work too, see the docs of `cfthread`.

Comment: Would it be possible to include a call to code to delete the file from within the dynamic cfm file itself?

Comment: That would bring you back to the same problem of the abort.

Comment: Steve Bryant, I have tried including the code on top of the dynamic cfm file. However if there is a compilation error none of it will run and the file will not get deleted.

Comment: How about putting the delete code in `onRequestEnd()` in `application.cfc` ?